# Is this statement always true about critical points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For any polynomial function in 3 variables, say $g$:$R^3$$\rightarrow$$R^n$ $g(x,y,z)$, do $g$'s critical points always occur in
$\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax formatting to mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What set are the variables $x$,$y$, and $z$ elements of? Is the function a real-valued function?

Comment: @AarohGokhale (x,y,z) from R^3(still learning LaTex) and g is real valued.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  MathJax command aren't effective unless they're enclosed in `$` signs. `$R^3$` will give you $R^3$, and `$\mathbb{R}^3$` will give you $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is each critical point given by three real numbers?

Comment: @JohnDouma yes, forgot to precise $g$:$R^3$ $\rightarrow$ $R^n$.

Comment: @silver_snaffles Yes, critical points are always element of the domain, so in this case $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @ndhanson3 thanks for clarifying